# Jquery: Loop through each sibling and give each of them a different class?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do I loop through each sibling and give each of them a different class? When one is active however I want all classes from the siblings to be removed.

Right now I got this:

```
$('.font-size').click(function() {
  $('.font-size.font-size-active').removeClass('font-size-active');
   $(this).addClass("font-size-active");
  });
```

So basically I got 3 font size divs. When user clicks on one the button changes the background color. So far I got it to work. Then however I want to give each of them a unique additional class which changes the font-size accordingly.

How do I do this? I have indexof in my mind but not entirely sure if it works and how to use it in this context.

Markup:

```
<span class="font-size">Small</span>
<span class="font-size">Medium</span>
<span class="font-size">Large</span>
```

**Edit:** .small, .medium, .large classes are added to a .content div depending on the button clicked.

Comment: Would you post the markup as well? Even better if you could post it on jsFiddle or similar.

Comment: Change `$('.font-size.font-size-active').removeClass('font-size-active');` to `$('.font-size').removeClass('font-size-active');`

Comment: @HanletEscaño I added the markup. So basically what happens is that the user clicks on small and the text in my .content div becomes small. If medium is clicked everything becomes medium sized and so on. So for the first font-size span I apply a class .small on the .content div second .medium and so on succesively.

Comment: *give each of them a unique additional class which changes the font-size accordingly*. What classes exactly do you want to add?

Comment: @dfsq .small, .medium, .large classes are added to the .content div depending on the button clicked

Comment: @dfsq hope that helps!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would set `data` attributes with the classes to add:

```
<span class="font-size" data-class="small">Small</span>
<span class="font-size" data-class="medium">Medium</span>
<span class="font-size" data-class="large">Large</span>
```

and then use it this way:

```
var $sizes = $('.font-size').click(function () {
    $sizes.removeClass('font-size-active');
    $(this).addClass("font-size-active");
    $('.content').removeClass('small medium large').addClass($(this).data('class'));
});
```

See the demo below.

```js
var $sizes = $('.font-size').click(function () {
    $sizes.removeClass('font-size-active');
    $(this).addClass("font-size-active");
    $('.content').removeClass('small medium large').addClass($(this).data('class'));
});
```

```css
.font-size {padding: 10px; display: inline-block;}
.font-size-active {background: #EEE;padding: 10px;}
.small {font-size: 80%;}
.medium {font-size: 100%;}
.large {font-size: 120%;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="font-size" data-class="small">Small</span>
<span class="font-size" data-class="medium">Medium</span>
<span class="font-size" data-class="large">Large</span>

<div class="content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Laborum molestias expedita quo ipsa enim quasi ea aspernatur rerum dolorum voluptatum saepe voluptate aliquam quibusdam veniam sint asperiores id est nesciunt!</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I just learned something new